# How can i programmatically implement a special viewgroup that has buttons and support swipe

Tags: android, scrollview, viewgroup

I want to implement a viewgroup that acting like the launcher application. It can be as width and height that i specified and it has the column and row size properties and has to provide paging. For example:

for one usage, say, i want to put screen 30 buttons. i want these buttons within a (w200dip h40dip) sized horizontal scroller. scroller has to paging support. and say, on each page i want 12 buttons (6 columns 2 rows).

(the image below)

haw can i implement this, thanks for every little help :)

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: so, how can i add paging property to grid? when i say paging, i mean to make horizontal swipe..

Comment: and also i cant find a way to use gridview on horizontal scrolling mode??